# What is the most optimal Cleric Subclass for a party consisting of mostly melee martials?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, archetype

I'm a cleric considering asking my DM for a subclass change. My character worships Hestia, so most domains might work, emphasis on Life and Light. My party consists of two melee fighters, a paladin, a rogue and a sorcerer. What subclass would synergize best with this party?

Here's how the party goes:

2 Melee-Oriented Fighters

1 Paladin(obviously melee-based)

1 Rogue(unsure of in combat terms)

1 Sorcerer(Blaster role, hasn't shown up recently, so don't consider)

1 Cleric(Me)

So I would say put an emphasis on support and damage when determining the subclass.

Comment: Given the discussion in the [other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208724/75095) where you say you play a ranger, can you please give some clear criteria what you want to maximize, and what you consider optimal? Does it matter what level you are? Can you describe typical combat tactics used?

Comment: For context, I play in two separate campaigns, one as a ranger, and one as a cleric. For the cleric campaign, after learning how poor healing magic is in comparison to most other magic, I want to switch out my subclass to something that can benefit the party. And I already stated what I'm looking for, that being a subclass that prioritizes support, with damage being a close second.

Comment: Related on [Does a party need a cleric/paladin?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46976) and [Will my party function without a healer?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93152)

Comment: I fully agree with Thomas' answer, but you may want to keep your questions open a bit longer to draw more eyes and answers. We're not as active as we used to be, so giving some time for others to contribute could get your more information.

Comment: Hi @Playmaker  Could you put in what it is you wish to focus on? Healing, support other melee, damage, something else?

Comment: Healing and support are my priorities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Twilight Domain is easily the most powerful cleric subclass.

[I’ve written about this before](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/198308/62294), describing the Twilight Domain as “stupidly powerful”. The chief offender for the Twilight Domain's dominance is the Twilight Sanctuary feature. Borrowing from my previous analysis, I state:

> ##### Twilight Sanctuary
>
> This is the feature that really matters here. Here's the short version: the published version of Twilight Sanctuary is too reliable and too powerful. It creates a 1d6+level hit points buffer for every ally, every round, for basically no cost. It doesn't even require concentration. It scales with cleric level, so it gets better as you level up.

The Twilight Sanctuary channel divinity is powerful and reliable. It allows the cleric to take a full array of offensive spell selections without compromising on healing ability. Just turn it on, and it does the healing for you, for free, and allows you to hack and slash or blast your way through fights with your choice of offensive options.

I played through much of *Rime of the Frostmaiden* as a Goliath Twilight cleric, and I was frequently the lead damage dealer while also providing ample healing support to my party.

Comment: Good pick, but I am worried about overshadowing my party.

Comment: @Playmaker That is within your control. I chose to focus my cleric on dealing damage with Twilight Sanctuary running. You can easily select for additional buff spells to use in tandem with Twilight Sanctuary and really make your allies shine.

Comment: @Playmaker If you’re worried about overshadowing, then consider not going for the most optimal:)

Comment: Gotcha I'll try out Light domain

Answer (score 2):

With lots of martial characters in your party the *Voice of Authority* feature of the **Order Domain cleric** (*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* p.31) might be fun because it keeps you thinking tactically about everyone else's position and potential damage.

> If you cast a spell with a spell slot of 1st level or higher and target an ally with the spell, that ally can use their reaction immediately after the spell to make one weapon attack against a creature of your choice that you can see.

Put on your heavy armour and start targeting allies with support spells. Once you are at a level with enough spare spell slots, you can spam Healing Word as a bonus action to trigger it regularly while also casting thematic cantrips alongside (Sacred Flame? multiclass dip a level Sorcerer for more hearth fire themed options), and could even be used to give your rogue a second go at sneak attack in a round.

Comment: Knowing what the twilight cleric is capable of, this simply isn’t the most optimal decision, and the question is asking for most optimal

Comment: very true, but I was try to answer a version of 'optimal' in relation to: "What subclass would synergize best with this party?" and "I am worried about overshadowing my party"

Comment: They want to focus on both support and damage. Is it really optimal for them to give up their primary action to allow someone to make a single melee attack? That analysis would help support this answer.